# Google DataStore - createdAt attribute and updates

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

It's often very useful to know when an entry / document has been created. But since it's not possible to update only a specific set of attributes in Google DataStore, it's hard to keep the value of createdAt over the life of the object.

Essentially it seems like in order to have a createdAt attribute with DataStore, the application must [get] the entry in order to retrieve the createdAt value, and then [update] it reusing that value. Of course this means more $$$ since every update will make 2 API requests instead of 1.

Is there something I am missing or is that the best way to go about this?

Comment: `an entry / document has been created` - do you mean a datastore entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for such functionality depends on the client library you use.

For example the [`ndb` client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/) recommended for the 1st generation App Engine applications offers such support. From [Date and Time Properties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#Date_and_Time):

> Each of these properties has two extra Boolean keyword options:
>
> **auto_now_add**
>
> Set property to current date/time when entity is created. You can
>   manually override this property. When the entity is updated, the
>   property doesn't change. For that behavior, use **auto_now**.
>
> **auto_now**
>
> Set property to current date/time when entity is created and whenever
>   it is updated.

So when you `put` the entity into the datastore without providing values for such properties (and they have these options set) they are automatically updated.

Comment: is this the only client lib that offer such support? In particular, does nodejs have an equivalent lib?

Comment: Is there a way to bypass `auto_now` momentarily when executing a system update, and only update on user action?